# How do i replace 2 or more whitespaces with a singleone? I need to replace a pattern with another pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not good at using regular expressions, so here's my question... 
I have this string

```
#   32 #asd #31223 #   asdf
```

And I need to get this:

```
# 32 Nasd #31223 N asdf
```

Let me explain:

1.- I need to remove 2 or more whitespaces with single one, I think solved it with:

```
Regex.Replace( RemoveDiacritics(text.ToUpper().Trim()), @"[ ]{2,}", @" ", RegexOptions.None);
```

2.- After that, if the regex find a #, it needs to check the next character, if it's a number, it's okay, but if the next character of # its a letter, I need to replace for a letter N.

Can you help me with the second requirement please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with two passes.

First pass:

```
var normalized = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"[\s]{2,}"," ");
```

Second pass:

```
var nReplaced  = Regex.Replace(normalized , @"#(?!\s*\d)", "N");
```

The second regex just uses a negative look ahead to find a `#` followed by a

*non digit*, and if it does it replaces it with `N`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("#   32 #asd #31223 #   asdf", @"[\s]{2,}"," ",RegexOptions.None);

result = Regex.Replace(result, @"#(\D)", new MatchEvaluator((m)=>
            {
                return "N" + m.Groups[1].Value;
            }));
```

Comment: Yes, that solve the part of the 2 or more whitespaces, but i need to replace the # for a letter N if its followed by a whitespace/no whitespace and a letter. Thank you.

Comment: Added part 2  to answer